Indexing array of colors and numbers
I tried to draw radial lines of different angles and colors from origin using arrays.

\documentclass[tikz, border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\def \angleArray {0,30,60,90,120,150,180} % degrees
\def \colorArray {blue, orange, maroon, purple, violet, navy, cyan}
\foreach \angle [count=\j] in   \angleArray {
    \draw[->, thick, rotate=\angle, \colorArray[\j]] (0,0) to (7, 0) node [above right, \colorArray[\j], rotate=\angle] {$\angle^\circ$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I followed this post, but got an error: Package pgfkeys error: don't know the key /tikz/blue, orange, ....?

You're missing \begin{document} and \begin{tikzpicture}. And \readlist if you followed the other answer.

I missed typing them. But it still doesn't work.

I didn't say that would fix the problem. But your code should reproduce the problem you want help with, including the text of the appropriate error.

This could achieve your goal. To ignore spaces in list of items, you need the star version of \readlist*. maroon and navy are not valid color names in xcolor package. I think you mean Marnoon from dvipsnames and Navy from svgnames. So, you need load these two options using the standalone document class options. To avoid square brackets conflicts in tikz option, you can put {} around \colorarray[\j].
\documentclass[dvipsnames,svgnames,tikz,border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\def \angleArray {0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180} % degrees
\readlist* \colorarray {blue, orange, Maroon, purple, violet, Navy, cyan}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \angle [count=\j from 1] in  \angleArray  {%
\draw[->, thick, rotate=\angle,{\colorarray[\j]}] (0,0) to (7, 0) node [above right,{\colorarray[\j]},rotate=\angle] {$\angle^\circ$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Please post compilable code or code which produces the error whose text you include in your question, if that's the issue.
You need \begin{document}, \begin{tikzpicture} and to define undefined colours. I just substituted standard colours.
You also need to \readlist to create the array.
Because the syntax relies on square brackets, pgf's parser has trouble, so retrieve the item from the array before using it.
Finally, you need to remove the spaces from the colour names or, again, define colours with these names. I removed the spaces.
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def \angleArray {0,30,60,90,120,150,180} % degrees
  \readlist \colorArray {blue,orange,red,purple,violet,brown,cyan}
  \foreach \angle [count=\j] in   \angleArray {
    \edef\tempa{\colorArray[\j]}
    \draw[->, thick, rotate=\angle, \tempa] (0,0) to (7, 0) node [above right, rotate=\angle, \tempa] {$\angle^\circ$};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Personally, I'd use LaTeX 3 for arrays. Be aware that listofitems is a generic TeX package which uses _ as a letter rater than @, just as LaTeX 3 does, but with (obviously) a completely different and non-standard syntax.
[The absence of visual results is a function of an Okular rather than a TeX bug. I'm responsible for many failures, but this isn't one of them.]

+1 Here's a more listofitems-centric variation: \documentclass[tikz, border=0.2cm]{standalone} \usepackage{listofitems} \begin{document} \begin{tikzpicture}   \readlist \angleArray {0,30,60,90,120,150,180} % degrees   \readlist \colorArray {blue,orange,red,purple,violet,brown,cyan}   \foreachitem \angle \in \angleArray[] {     \draw[->, thick, rotate=\angle, {\colorArray[\anglecnt]}] (0,0) to (7, 0)        node [above right, rotate=\angle, {\colorArray[\anglecnt]}] {$\angle^\circ$};   } \end{tikzpicture} \end{document}

Thank you for the fix. First, I had colors 'maroon' and 'navy' that are not recognized by tikz. Second, there cannot be spaces between \colorArray entries, else got errors like "I do not know the key '/tikz/ blue'. Number arrays can have spaces though like \angleArray {0, 30, 60,..].

@StevenB.Segletes I figured that was another way to go, but there might be reasons to handle the first list with \foreach. But I don't know listofitems at all. In fact, I didn't know it even existed until I answered this question and the comments in the code are in neither English nor Welsh ;). (Given most of my code is generously sprinkled with Welsh, at best, this is not a complaint.)

I find the attempts with listofitems and \foreach quite clumsy.
It's not difficult to define a small infrastructure for managing lists of items and retrieving items from them.
Here we just want to do as many steps as the number of angles, so a “number foreach” cycle is easier: the current index can be referred to as #1.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\definelist}{mm}
 {
  \clist_clear_new:c { l_cheonlang_list_#1_clist }
  \clist_set:cn { l_cheonlang_list_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\listcount}{m}
 {
  \clist_count:c { l_cheonlang_list_#1_clist }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\listitem}{mm}
 {
  \clist_item:cn { l_cheonlang_list_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\nforeach}{O{1}mm}
 {
  \int_step_inline:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  makeray/.style={
    rotate=\listitem{angles}{#1},
    color=\listitem{colors}{#1},
  },
]
\definelist{angles}{0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180}
\definelist{colors}{blue, orange, Maroon, purple, violet, Navy, cyan}
\nforeach{\listcount{angles}}{
  \draw[->,thick,makeray=#1] (0,0) to (7, 0) node [above right,makeray=#1]
    {$\listitem{angles}{#1}^\circ$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Note that defining a style makes the code much more compact.


Just in case you did not consider that the \foreach allows you to assemble arrangements of multiple properties per iteration, that in my opinion visualizing the correspondence in that way is better than having them separated, but perhaps you want it to be like this so that you can perform other operations, but if you were to use them within in a for environment you can use them or not depending on whether you put them in the drawing instructions.
RESULT:

MWE:
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\MyArray{%Angle/Color
            0/orange,
            15/yellow,
            30/lime,
            45/green,
            60/SeaGreen,
            75/Cyan,
            90/NavyBlue,
            105/blue,
            120/violet,
            135/magenta,
            150/RubineRed,
            165/red,
            180/BrickRed%
        }
        \foreach \angle/\clr  in \MyArray {
            \draw[->, thick,draw=\clr] (0,0) -- (\angle:7) node [anchor=180+\angle, text=\clr] {$\angle^\circ$};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

